# How can I get a listview hiddenfield and use it in codebehind oncheckedchanged function

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview, checkbox

```
<asp:ListView ID="TasksList" runat="server" DataKeyNames="AnnualProgramTasksId"
 DataSourceID="TasksListSqlDataSource">    
...
<LayoutTemplate>...</LayoutTemplate>
...
 <ItemTemplate>
      <tr>
         <td>
             <asp:HiddenField ID="AnnualProgramTasksId" runat="server" Value='<%#Bind("AnnualProgramTasksId")%>'/>
             <asp:Checkbox ID="CompletedCheckbox" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="CompletedCheckboxChange" Checked='<%#IIf(Eval("TaskCompleted"), "True", "False")%>' />
         </td>
         <td><%#Eval("TaskDesc")%></td>
         <td></td>
      </tr>  
 </ItemTemplate>
...
 <asp:sqldatasource ID="TasklistSqlDataSource...
SelectCommand="Select AnnualProgramTasksId, TaskDesc, TaskCompleted FROM AnnualPreogramTasks"
</asp:sqldatasource>
```

...

Code Behind:

```
Protected Sub CompletedCheckboxChange( ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs )
     Dim Completed As CheckBox = TryCast( sender, CheckBox )

     response.write( Completed.Checked ) ' This works. I'll use this to determine what to enter in the database for the 'Checked' column
     ' **How can i get the value of AnnualProgramTasksId?**  
     ' (I'll use this to construct a sql statement to update the appropriate database row.

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim AnnualProgramTasksId as HiddenField = TryCast(Completed.Parent.FindControl("AnnualProgramTasksId"), HiddenField)
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  Just had to use AnnualProgramTasksId.Value to get the actual value I wanted to use in the sql.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Something like this would work, havent tested it though

```
Dim AnnualProgramTasksId As New List(Of Integer)
        For Each task As ListViewItem In Me.TasksList.Items
            Dim CompletedCheckboxs As CheckBox = DirectCast(task.FindControl("CompletedCheckbox"), CheckBox)
            If CompletedCheckboxs IsNot Nothing Then
                If CompletedCheckboxs.Checked Then
                    Dim HiddenProductID As HiddenField = DirectCast(task .FindControl("AnnualProgramTasksId"), HiddenField)
                    Dim ID As String = CInt(HiddenProductID.Value.ToString)
                End If
        Next
```